# Look for item value in localstroge

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, arrays

I have a $localstroge with the below stored value:

```
{"EmployerDetails":{"Distance":30,"EmpLatitude":51.3353899,"EmpLongitude":-0.742856,"EmpNo":39424,"Insitution":null,"PlaceName":"Camberley","TalentPoolLicences":[{"Membership":[{"Identity":39424,"Name":"Weydon Secondary School"}],"TalentPoolType":1},{"Membership":[{"Identity":2,"Name":"North East Hampshire"},{"Identity":4,"Name":"Surrey"},{"Identity":8,"Name":"Surrey"}],"TalentPoolType":3}]},"FacetFilters":{"LastActivity":0,"LocationFilterType":1,"fullorparttime_pex":null,"religion":null,"soughtphase_swk":null,"soughtrole_swk":null,"soughtsubject_swk":null},"LookingFor":null,"OrderBy":null,"PageIndex":1,"PageSize":40}
```

How can I get the Identity value out from it that sits inside EmployerDetails. I have tried below but it never gets inside if condition:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {      
 if (localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) === 'EmployerDetails')
            { console.log('hello'); }
}
```

Any help on this please?

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the items to localstorage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're searching for nested key first you need to grab the object and also need to parse it to JSON with JSON.parse then you can proceed as we do in case on normal javascript object

```
localStorage.getItem('signup-prefs')
```

This gives me a string containing my object

```
""name":"google","oauth_version":"2.0","oauth_server":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","openid":"","username":""}"
```

After parsing it we can get the object and now we can find the desired property.

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('signup-prefs'))`

```
Object {name: "google", oauth_version: "2.0", oauth_server: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", openid: "", username: ""}
```

Coming to your problem

Let's say your employee information is like this i am not showing all the fields here.

```
var empData = {"EmployerDetails":Distance":30,"EmpLatitude":51.33538}}
```

Then you set the key like this

```
localstorage.setItem('empData', JSON.stringify(empData))
```

Now get the string object by key parse it to Json and find the desired key from the object loop over it to get the result.I haven't tested it but i am confident it will work. Let me know if not.

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
     if (localStorage.key(i) === 'empData') {

        // Parse the string to json

         var empData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('empData'));

        // get all the keys
         var keys = Object.keys(empData);

         for (var idx = 0; idx < keys.length; idx++) {
            // find the desired key here
             if (keys[idx] == 'EmployeeDetails') {
                 var empDetails = empData[keys[idx]]
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

One important thing about your code is 
this statement `localStorage.key(i)) === 'EmployerDetails'` returns either true or false and writing like this
`if(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) === 'EmployerDetails')` will never was executed because you didn't have any key with that name(In practice we should never use keyword as key) .

Comment: Cheers body I got it working. Thanks for your help on this. however would be good to know your prefer approach to get the matching value out if exist.

Comment: There are several ways like you can do a Object.keys. Hang on let me add the code here..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to convert it to the json object and then gets the values out?